# JavaScript embedded in HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, function, drop-down-menu

I have a piece of javascript code that causes a text box to appear adjacent to a drop-down menu when a certain selection is made. It worked perfectly until I embedded it in html. I'm not sure *why* it's not working now, although it's probably really trivial.

Here is the function, as it is now:

```
$public->html .= '<script type="text/javascript">;
    $(function(){
    // initially check the default value in dd_question
    if($("#dd_question").find("option:selected").val() == "0"){
            $("#other_question").show();
          }else{
            $("#other_question").hide();
          }
        $("#dd_question").change(function() {
          if($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "0"){
            $("#other_question").show();
          }else{
            $("#other_question").hide();
          }
        });
    });
  </script>';
```

It would be great to have this working again. Can anyone see why it's not?

Comment: where is it not working?

Comment: Please try to narrow your code down to a small, relevant portion. It's difficult and time-consuming to read your entire source code- a more compact example will net you more answers.

Comment: It just doesn't display anything, except for the textbox (no matter what selection is made, though)

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: `$public->html` v.s. `$page->html` is about the only oddity in the snippet you've provided, which is not enough to really fix the problem. Plus, for assigning blocks of text to a variable, you really should look into using a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) instead of a multiline quoted string.

Comment: @MarcB That was actually it! Wow, what a dumb mistake! If you make your comment an answer, I will choose it as the best answer. Otherwise, +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not php user but i can tell you that the semi colon at this line probably shouldn't be there.

```
$public->html .= '<script type="text/javascript">;
```

Answer (score 1):

Waste of code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#dd_question").change(function() {
    var show = $(this).val() == "0";
    if (show) $("#other_question").show();
    else      $("#other_question").hide();
  }).change();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Someone PLEASE Format this for me? My iPhone is no help at all